# Configuring cygwin for building ndk project

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, native-code

I have searched on the Internet a lot and I'm trying to build my ndk files and then include them to my Android project on eclipse. After searching on Internet I came to know that cygwin is required to build ndk project. I have downloaded the necessary files for cygwin, however I'm blank for the next step. i.e steps for how to build my ndk files on cygwin terminal and then include them to my eclipse android project. Kindly help me on these steps. Would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest ndk release you do not need cygwin. Just run`ndk-build.cmd` windows command file which comes with the ndk. It is that way starting from ndk revision 8.

Study OVERVIEW.html in the android-ndk/docs subdir. Also there is a 'samples' subdir in the android-ndk, study hello-jni in there and try to build and run it. Also there is a book ['Android NDK Beginner's Guide'](http://wowebook.be/book/android-ndk-beginners-guide/#) look it up on the net it covers basically everything

Comment: i have downloaded android ndk-r8b . am clueless how to use this for building my ndk files! can you please mention it step by step? i would be greatful. the paths how to set them!