# NDK eclipse configuration

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, cygwin

I am trying to configure NDK in Eclipse. I had no idea what to do. I tried following lots of tutorials, but it didnt work.
I get this message when i try to build:

[image]

Though i set the path correctly. Even if i didnt it should be working because i am using the latest version of NDK, where the **ndk-build** command is already there and doesnt need Cygwin.
I tried these
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670855/error-program-ndk-build-cmd-is-not-found-in-path),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111919/configuring-cygwin-for-building-ndk-project),[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825534/set-build-path-in-eclipse-for-ndk-program) but still no solution.

I have also a weird message, in the toolchain editor.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First you should downlode NDK this link(dl.google.com/service/prod_unavailable.html) and then unzip file and copy to android folder in your pc. go to this part in eclipse:

Windows->Preference->android-> NDK->browse your NDK file. now you can use ndk.

Create a class of java and then use these picture:

1.i.stack.imgur.com/PGBYE.png

2.i.stack.imgur.com/fnIYI.png

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the NDK path to the System path and restarting Eclipse.

Here you have how to change the path in Windows http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm